# How to insert multiple row (array of objects) without using loop in Laravel?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, eloquent

I am using Angular as front end and parameters that is send to post in laravel is array of objects. I want to insert the bulk of elements without using loop. Is is possible?? If yes how can I achieve that??

**RoomAvailability Controller in Php**

```
public function storeRoomAvailability()
{
    $roomId = request();
    $test = RoomAvailability::where('room_id', $roomId->room_id)->get();
    if (is_null($test)) {

        return response()->json([
            'success' => false,
            'message' => 'The room is already taken'
        ]);
    } else {

        $roomAvailability = RoomAvailability::create([$this->validateRequest()]);

        return response()->json([
            'success' => true,
            'message' => 'Room Availability has been created successfully.',
            'data' => $roomAvailability
        ]);
    }
}

private function validateRequest()
{
    return request()->validate([
        'room_id' => 'required |unique:room_availabilities',
        'reservation_id' => 'nullable',
        'booking_id' => 'required',
        'check_in_date' => 'required',
        'check_out_date' => 'required'
    ]);
}
```

**Parameters from Angular 8**

```
[
  {
    "reservation_id": 25,
    "room_id": 1,
    "check_in_date": "2020-04-27 12:00:00",
    "check_out_date": "2020-04-30 12:00:00",
    "availability": false,
    "status": "booked",
    "booking_id": 26
   },
  {
    "reservation_id": 26,
    "room_id": 2,
    "check_in_date": "2020-04-27 12:00:00",
    "check_out_date": "2020-04-30 12:00:00",
    "availability": false,
    "status": "booked",
    "booking_id": 26
   }
]
```

Comment: Is your code currently working? I don't understand `$roomId = request();`. IS your code working?

Comment: you can use [insert ()](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#inserts) method to perform the bulk insert of the array at once and if your array is in perfect condition then yes you can insert it without loop(I don't suggest it tho do some validation etc)

Comment: @ChristopheHubert Yes the code is working fine

Comment: Thank You @AnujShrestha.. I will try

Comment: Have you managed to use `insert()`? You need to change as well your validation to use arrays 

Comment: No, I couldn't use it. How can I use it. @ChristopheHubert

Answer (score 0):

first convert the parameters that comes from angular to associative arrays

```
$arrayValues=json_decode($Parameters_from_Angular,true);
```

then, insert the new values using bulk insert:

```
RoomAvailability::insert($arrayValues);
```

Comment: I tried using json_decode but it is throwing exception saying "json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given". I tried converting the above array into json array using JSON.stringy from angular. But it is  still showing the same error??

Comment: you should put your json between quotes in one line, copy and past this then try:
$json= '[{"reservation_id": 25, "room_id": 1, "check_in_date": "2020-04-27 12:00:00", "check_out_date": "2020-04-30 12:00:00", "availability": false, "status": "booked", "booking_id": 26}, {"reservation_id": 26, "room_id": 2, "check_in_date": "2020-04-27 12:00:00", "check_out_date": "2020-04-30 12:00:00", "availability": false, "status": "booked", "booking_id": 26}]';
$value=json_decode($json);